# Time series feature detection

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-selection

I'm trying to build a model that given the blue line in the graph below (my time series data) and the red lines (features manually labeled by myself) is able to detect similar features/patters in un-labeled data.

My question is whether someone can suggest an algorithm to use in order to achieve that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Yes.

If you are looking for pattern detection in time series, than you can find an efficient solution in this paper [Stream Monitoring under the Time Warping Distance](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~christos/PUBLICATIONS/ICDE07-spring.pdf) using an efficient dynamic time warping approach (DTW).

Yet I am not certain whether you are specifically looking for pattern recognition or whether you wish to detect spikes/increase within a time series. If you are going to the second target, other approaches are more suitably such as you find in this presentation. [Change detection in monitoring time series](http://changes-itn.eu/Portals/0/Content/2013/Barcelonnette/Thom_Change%20detection2.pdf).

If you enhance your question with detail and motivation, then this will have a strong positive effect on the quality and detail of answers.